# What does this thing in app.yaml mean

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, yaml

Here is app.yaml code

```
application: hellodashboard
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /oauth2callback
  script: oauth2client/appengine.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

I wanted to know what does

```
 - url: /oauth2callback
  script: oauth2client/appengine.py
```

mean?
I know the second line indicate that there is a script called appengine.py in oauth2client directory.But what does **url:/oauth2callback** indicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that there is a handler in the `oauth2client/appengine.py` file that handles requests to the url `/oauth2callback`

Comment: Ha, +1 since you beat me to it :)

Comment: So where does it actually redirect to.I mean the application.Where do we need to configure that?

Comment: You need a file called `appengine.py` in a folder called `oauth2client`. It needs to define a handler class that derives from the `webapp2.RequestHandler` class. It should define methods for handling actions such as `GET`, `POST` etc.

Comment: Maybe you need to start here. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp

Answer (score 1):

The portion after `-url:` indicates how your application will handle calls to that particular URL. With your example (which is for OAuth2), when your application receives a request in the form of `/oauth2callback`, instead of looking inside of `main.py` to figure out how to handle the request, it uses the file found at `oauth2client/appengine.py`